# How to detect who kills a certain player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a juggernaut game in Minecraft, and I need to know how to detect when someone kills the juggernaut and then do something to that player (like set a dummy objective "juggernaut" to 1 for that player).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the objective type to `stat.teamkill.dark_red (or other color)`

Place the juggernaut on a team and set that team's color to match the objective criteria

When you end the game, use the selector `@p[score_Juggernaut_min=1]` to find out who won.

Comment: I totally forgot that there is a scoreboard objective that goes up when you kill a player on a certain color team, I recommend using this instead.